# Google Cloud : Bearer token generated from service account gives "insufficient_scope" error

Tags: oauth-2.0, gcloud, bearer-token

I have a Google Cloud service account and I'm able to use its JSON key to query google cloud data store via GCP python client libraries. 
I'm using the very same JSON to generate a bearer token to run the same request via curl but this fails with "insufficient_scope" error.

Steps used to generate Bearer Token:

`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=KEY_FILE`

`TOKEN=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`

curl command used with bearer token:

`curl 'https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my_project:runQuery' \
  -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"gqlQuery":{"queryString":"select * from Tasktest111"}}' \
  --compressed`

Comment: Looking further into this, it seems the token generated by above service account had a very narrow scope. [this tool](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo) proved to be super helpful in checking the token scope. Tried creating a token from my personal gcloud account with a much wider service account, and the all the required scopes were found.

Comment: Adding Cloud function developer has worked for me, but it might not be the best solution.